# Errors that I don't know how to fix

Tags: scripting, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var targetscript : Diamond;
var yellow : Color(1,0.92,0.016,1);
var cyan : Color(0,1,1,1);
var green : Color(0,1,0,1);
var red : Color(1,0,0,1);
var magenta : Color(1,0,1,1);
var black : Color(0,0,0,1);

function Start () {
    gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = yellow;
}


function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(yellow, cyan);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 9) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(cyan, green);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 14) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(green, red);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 19) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, magenta);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 24) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(magenta);
    }

}
```

It gives me these errors:

```
Assets/Scripts/colour.js(4,22): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.
Assets/Scripts/colour.js(4,22): BCE0044: expecting EOF, found '0.92'.
Assets/Scripts/colour.js(4,21): BCE0044: expecting ), found ','.
Assets/Scripts/colour.js(4,19): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.
```

I don't find any missing semicolons! I don't find anything wrong with the colors! why does it give me so many errors? I checked the script more than 5 times but I don't find anything wrong! Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing variable declaration with assignment to a class I think each of the color declaration need to look similar to this:

```
var yellow = new Color(1,0.92,0.016,1);
```

This creates a yellow variable with a Color type and we create a new instance of it and assign it to yellow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xxx: yyy = zzz;
```

This is how you declare a variable in Unityscript, where xxx is the name of the variable, yyy is the type of the variable and zzz is the value.
In your case, you wanted to define a type but you defined a value instead, thus the error appeared.

Change all of them to be:

```
var yellow : Color;
var cyan : Color;
var green : Color;
var red : Color;
var magenta : Color;
var black : Color;
```

Then in `Start()` function, give them value:

```
yellow = Color(1,0.92,0.016,1);
cyan = Color(0,1,1,1);
green = Color(0,1,0,1);
red = Color(1,0,0,1);
magenta = Color(1,0,1,1);
black = Color(0,0,0,1);
```

Comment: `Assets/Scripts/colour.js(40,63): BCE0017: The best overload for the method 'UnityEngine.Color.Lerp(UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color, float)' is not compatible with the argument list '(UnityEngine.Color)'.`

Comment: `Color.Lerp` uses 3 parameters as stated [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html). The first parameter is the color you want to be lerped, the second is the color you want it to lerp to, and the third is the time of lerp process. The third parameter is optional.

Comment: The error you're getting is because you used only 1 parameter somewhere in your code. Possibly this: `gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(magenta);`. You need to specify the before and after color in the first and second parameters.

Comment: sorry it was meant to be (magenta, black); it was a copy and paste error.  but I get the `Assets/Scripts/colour.js(33,63): BCE0017: The best overload for the method 'UnityEngine.Color.Lerp(UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color, float)' is not compatible with the argument list '(UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color)'.` error

Comment: Try adding a third parameter, which is time of lerping process. That should work.

Comment: I've posted a link to unity3d official reference about Color.Lerp [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this

```
#pragma strict
var targetscript : Diamond;
var yellow : Color = Color(1,0.92,0.016,1);
var cyan : Color = Color(0,1,1,1);
var green : Color = Color(0,1,0,1);
var red : Color = Color(1,0,0,1);
var magenta : Color = Color(1,0,1,1);
var black : Color = Color(0,0,0,1);

function Start () {
    gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = yellow;
}


function Update () {
    if (targetscript.score > 4) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(yellow, cyan);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 9) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(cyan, green);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 14) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(green, red);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 19) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(red, magenta);
    }

    if (targetscript.score > 24) {
        gameObject.camera.backgroundColor = Color.Lerp(magenta);
    }

}
```